# Computing limit of $f(x) = x^{(\frac{1}{x} - 1)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f(x) = x^{(\frac{1}{x} - 1)}$ . Find $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$ if it exists .

**My try** : $f(x) = x^{(\frac{1}{x} - 1)} = e^{\frac{(1-x) \ln x}{x}}$ . I'm not allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule but intuitively seems the answer is zero .

Comment: The base tends to $0$ and exponent tends to $\infty$ so the desired limit is $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How we can prove that statement ?

Comment: Proving this is at the same level as proving that $1/x\to\infty$ as $x\to 0^{+}$. Such proofs should not be demanded as a part of exercise but should rather form a part of your understanding. For that purpose let $0<x<1/2$ then $0<x^{(1/x)-1}<x$ and you can either use Squeeze Theorem or the $\epsilon, \delta $ definition of limit.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not indeterminate when $x\to 0^+$:

- $\ln x\to -\infty$,
- $1-x\to 1$, so $(1-x)\ln x\to-\infty$
- the denominator tends to $0^+$
  so the exponent tends to $-\infty$, and the exponential indeed tends to $0$.

Comment: How we can make it in a rigorous way ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(1-x)\log{x}}{x}=\frac{1-x}{x}\log{x}=(\frac{1}{x}-1)\log{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{(\frac{1}{x}-1)}=+\infty \text{ and } \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{\log{x}}=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{(\frac{1}{x}-1)\log{x}}=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{x^{\frac{1}{x}-1}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}{e^{\frac{(1-x)\log{x}}{x}}}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: remember $\infty \times - \infty= -\infty.$Take $e$ and $\ln$. Also, since $e$ is a continuous function so it behaves nicely with limit. I hope it should be clear now.